# How to save a snapshot of Django test database

Tags: python, django, sqlite, unit-testing, django-fixtures

**Background**

I'm trying to replace fixtures in my unit tests with model factories (using Factory Boy). It would help for me to determine why the current unit tests are failing if I could look at the database generated by loading the fixtures and compare them to the data generated by the factories.

I have tried to use the `--keepdb` flag when running the tests to save a copy of the test database but this doesn't seem to save an accessible database anywhere.

**Question**

Django test databases are discarded after the tests run. Is there any way to  save a copy of a database before it is deleted?

Alternatively, is there a better way to compare the data created by a fixture file and the data created by a model factory?

Comment: can you add a breakpoint in your tests, then look at the database values?

Comment: @JamesRusso I believe a test database exists only in memory. How would I access the database to view the values?

Comment: I haven't worked with Django yet, but I know in ruby on rails the test database actually exists when you run tests and can be accessible for queries. At my work we have a postgresql database and there is a test database that is accessible that is loaded with our fixtures when running tests and you can query it during tests. I would it assume it would be similar for Django but could be wrong